# How do I write the qualified name of a symbol in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, identifier, qualified-name

I've got a name clash between two different Haskell modules that want to use the same infix operator (`<*>`).  The Haskell 98 report says that

```
modid.varsym
```

is permitted, but I can't get it to work.  In their entirety here are `Test.hs`:

```
module Test
where

import qualified Test2 as T

three = T.<*>
```

and `Test2.hs`:

```
module Test2
where
(<*>) = 3
```

But trying to compile results in an error message:

```
Test.hs:6:12: parse error on input `T.<*>'
```

I tried `T.(<*>)` but that doesn't work either.

How can I refer to a symbolic name defined in a module imported by `import qualified`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try

```
three = (T.<*>)
```

It's weird to define an infix operator as an integer. Let's consider `\\` (the set difference operator):

```
import qualified Data.List as L

foo = [1..5] L.\\ [1..3] -- evaluates to [4,5]
diff = (L.\\)
```

As you can see above, `L.\\` is a qualified infix operator; and it still works as an infix operator. To use it as a value, you put parentheses around the whole thing.

Comment: Weird indeed, but I was trying to make the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that we import symbols wrapped parens. E.g.

```
import T ((<*>))
```

so importing qualified is the same:

```
import qualified T as Q

main = print (Q.<*>)
```

Comment: This is a strange explanation... the first line isn't really relevant to the rest. Surely the first line should be "Remember that not-fully applied operators need to be parenthesized." And then have 'f = (<*>)' vs. 'f = (M.<*>)'.