# give (without duplicates) the names of actors who have co-starred in at least one film with a particular actor

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, template-haskell

I'm writing a movie database with Haskell. Like the title says, I am trying to give (without duplicates) the names of actors who have co-starred in at least one film with a particular actor.

Here's my code until now:

```
import Text.Printf
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import Data.Foldable 

type Title = String
type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]
type Period = (Year, Year)

data Film = Film Title Cast Year Fans
deriving(Show,Read,Eq)




testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [(Film "Casino Royale" ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"] 2006 ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),       
            (Film "Cowboys & Aliens" ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"] 2011 ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),         
            (Film "Catch Me If You Can" ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"] 2002 ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"]),
            (Film "Mamma Mia!" ["Meryl Streep", "Pierce Brosnan", "Colin Firth"] 2008 ["Kevin", "Jo", "Liz", "Amy", "Sam", "Zoe"]),
            (Film "Titanic" ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet"] 1997 ["Zoe", "Amy", "Heidi", "Jo", "Megan", "Olga"]),
            (Film "Quantum of Solace" ["Daniel Craig", "Judi Dench"] 2008 ["Bill", "Olga", "Tim", "Zoe", "Paula"])]

coactors :: Actor -> [Film] -> [Actor]  
coactors [] = []
coactors a -> filter (/= a) . nub . concatMap (\(Film _ c _ _) -> if a     `elem` c then c else [])
```

This is my try for a function that does what I said above. It doesn't work, and I don't know why. Can anyone provide me with correction that will make the function work?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says,

```
 Ambiguous occurrence `elem'
 It could refer to either `Data.List.elem',
                          imported from `Data.List' 
                          (and originally defined in `GHC.List')
                       or `Data.Foldable.elem',
                          imported from `Data.Foldable'
```

The problem is that the function `elem` is defined and exported in modules `Data.List` and `Data.Foldable`. You need to qualify the occurrence of `elem` (or `` `elem` ``, in infix notation) to `Data.List.elem`, if that's the version you want.

Alternatively, you can qualify you imports instead:

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Foldable as DF
```

This means you can use `elem` from `Data.List` unqualified as `elem`, but if you want to use the `Data.Foldable` version, you have to use the qualified version `DF.elem` (or `` `DF.elem` ``, in infix notation). The downside is that you also have to qualify every other use of a `Data.Foldable` function.

Alternatively, you can hide `elem` in `Data.Foldable`:

```
import Data.List -- import all of Data.List unqualified
import Data.Foldable hiding (elem) -- import all of Data.Foldable unqualified, but hide `elem`.
```

[This link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import) has everything you'll need. There are also many SO questions about qualifying namespaces, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741184/how-do-i-write-the-qualified-name-of-a-symbol-in-haskell).

Comment: You can also replace `foldMap` with `concatMap` and get rid of the `Data.Foldable` import entirely.

Comment: @dontask You would greatly benefit from a Haskell tutorial, which you can find out more about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016986/925978).

Comment: Another question I have is this.do u know how could I use this function to make a call with a given co-actor?im saying this because I don't know how to do it if I assign it to a variable which doesn't have anything to do with the calculation of the expression.in other words,does my code fully work ?(given what I want it to do?)

Comment: @dontask 1. Unclear what you're asking. 2. You have to do your own homework. 3. Read a tutorial. 4. You *might*(???) be looking for a `let` statement? 5. Read a tutorial.